# Videos not playing in my android app

Tags: android, flash, android-browser

Why are the videos not playing inside my app.

I have developed an android application, I use `mobile firefox browser` to browse inside it. Now when I try to play video's they won't play.

I tried the same with the **.apk** generated from build of the browser I am using inside my app and it works fine.

- For youtube videos- It opens the website and shows all the videos
  available but won't play them.
- for Foxnews.com- It says Error: source not supported.
- for facebook.com- It says flash player missing. (but I have flash
  player installed on my device).

Do I need to give any special permissions for my app to use the flash player installed on my device.

I am also getting this error

```
ERROR/GeckoConsole(9981): [JavaScript Warning: "Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration." {file: "http://m.youtube.com/?reload=5&rdm=mgsa03563#/watch?v=EZEgO1fngnE" line: 13}]
01-21 12:55:18.475: ERROR/GeckoConsole(9981): [JavaScript Warning: "Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped." {file: "http://m.youtube.com/?reload=5&rdm=mgsa03563#/watch?v=EZEgO1fngnE" line: 13}]
```

Comment: which device you used ? what is it's OS version ?? post your code or log cat

Comment: I am facing the same problem in both nexus 7-android 4.2.1 and htc sensation android 2.3

Comment: are you sure the user who uploaded this video has enabled mobile view

Comment: i can play the same video outside my app.